# How to insert SAS table data as well as hard coded values into DB2 database in SAS

Tags: sas, db2

I’m new to SAS getting the error BldngID(SAS table column) is not recognised or not found error when I try to access data from a sas table ‘DENSITY’ to insert into a DB2 table ‘PI_INTERN’. Is it not possible to directly specify SAS table columns to insert into DB2 ?

Here is my code:

```
Proc sql;
Connect to DB2(SSID=DSNT);
Create table DENSITY as
Select BldngID, Num_Tenure
From PIDB;
Disconnect from DB2;

%Put &Sqlxmsg;
%Put &Sqlxrc;
```

In SAS log: Table WORK.DENSITY created with 4 rows and 2 columns.

```
/* Insert into PI_INTERN table
Data _NULL_;
Set DENSITY;
Call execute(“Proc SQL;
Connect to DB2(SSID=DSNT);
Execute
(Insert into XXXX.PI_INTERN
(BldngID,
Num_Tenure,
UserID,
Tme_Upd)
Values
(BldngID,
Num_Tenure,
’AAB1’,
Current Timestamp))
By DB2;
Disconnect from DB2;
Quit;”);
%Put &Sqlxmsg;
%Put &Sqlxrc;
Run;
```

Comment: Are you required to use SQL Pass through? The easiest way is to create a libname statement and then use a standard PROC SQL. Pass through literally passes commands to the SQL system so it doesn't have access to your SAS datasets, especially local or work tables.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, one is to connect to the DB using a LIBNAME statement and then use PROC APPEND to insert data.

```
libname demo odbc dsn="myDB" schema='dbo';

proc append base=demo.dbTable data=sashelp.class;
run;
```

Otherwise, you can generate the INSERT INTO statements from a data step using CALL EXECUTE.

This is an example of how that works with querying a data set not (inserting) but should give you a solid idea of how it works. First you need to make sure you have the query designed and then try and make it via CALL EXECUTE()

I used str# variables as intermediary steps so you can see the code being generated and how it works to build your own.

```
*create fake data to simulate ID list;
data have;
input id $;
cards;
Alfred
Jane
;
run;

Data demo;
set have end=eof;

*this runs once at the beginning only;
if _n_=1 then
    do;
        str1 = "proc sql stimer ;
            select * from sashelp.class
            where name in (";
        call execute(str1);
    end;

 *this changes for each line;
str2 = quote(trim(id));
call execute(str2);

*this runs once for every line EXCEPT the last line, adds a comma for the query to be valid;
if not eof then do;
    str3 = ", ";
    call execute(str3);
 end;

*this runs once, only at the end to close query;
if eof then
    do;
       str4 = ");";
        call execute(str4);
    end;
run;
```